# Nearest neighbor distribution seems to fail empirical test

Tags: probability-distributions

I'm attempting to use the nearest neighbour distribution to understand the separation between uniformly distributed points in a high-dimensional space.
I find that there is discrepancy between empirical results and the analytic distribution and density functions when I look at high-dimension.

- How do I modify the analytic derivation to accurately reflect the empirical observations shown below?
- Am I violating some assumption in the empirical setup?

## Nearest neighbour distribution derivation

- Consider a homogeneous point point process with constant rate $\lambda$, then the Lebesgue measure of a point falling in a spherical shell $(r,r + \mathrm{d}r)$ is,

\begin{align}
\mu(r) = \lambda S(r)\mathrm{d}r
\end{align}
where $S(r) = V'(r)$ is the surface area of the hyper-sphere of radius $r$.

The probability of a nearest neighbour (NN) falling in $(r, r+\mathrm{d}r)$ is the probability of a point falling in $(r, r+\mathrm{d}r)$  and no points falling in $(0, r)$,

\begin{align}
P(NN \in (r, r+\mathrm{d}r)) \mathrm{d}r = (\lambda S(r)\mathrm{d}r) \left(1 - \int_0^r P(NN \in (r, r+\mathrm{d}r)) \mathrm{d}r \right)
\end{align}

The second factor is the probability of no points falling in $(0, r)$, and is one minus the probability of a point falling in $(0, r)$. Differentiate both sides, and then it becomes simple to arrive at,

\begin{align}
\log P(NN \in (r, r+\mathrm{d}r)) = -\lambda V(r) + \log S(r).
\end{align}

From this we can solve, and arrive at,
\begin{align}
P(NN \in (r, r+\mathrm{d}r)) = \lambda S(r) e^{-\lambda V(r)}
\end{align}
and the cummulative distribution function,
\begin{align}
P(NN \in (0, r)) = 1 - e^{-\lambda V(r)}.
\end{align}

This cumulative distribution function is the nearest neighbour distribution function.

## Comparing to empirical results

One of the most powerful tools in statistics is that we can often cheaply simulate the results and see if our analytic results are correct.

- I simulate $N$ points in $\mathcal{U}[0,1]^n$, so that $\lambda = N$.
- Then I compute the nearest neighbours and plot the histogram.
- For low dimensions I find a good agreement.
- For high dimensions I find a large discrepancy.

### agreement on low dimension

[image][image]

### discrepancy on high dimension

[image][image]

Comment: I am no expert on this topic, but my main concern would be related to the curse of dimensionality. For high dimensions, it can be shown that most of the volume lies within a narrow shell at the boundary. From this, I would expect the NN distribution to underestimate the distance needed. For this reason, there may be a better way to simulate the process. I don't believe the analytical NN distribution is incorrect.

Comment: I also don't think NN distribution is incorrect. How might one either modify the assumptions of the NN distribution derivation, or modify the simulation process to account for the discrepancy?

Comment: This may help, but I am not sure... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_hypercube_sampling

Comment: So it seems the answer to my first question is that I need to simulate with toroidal boundary conditions. This is because the derivation assumes a point process over an infinite extent volume, i.e. a ball placed around any point in the process never intersects with the boundary. The integral term in the derivation would need to be modified to account for a boundary, which is non-trivial to do.